# Use of Workmanager

Tags: java, apache, workmanagers

What is the use of the following Code in java below:

```
WorkManager manager = (WorkManager) initialContext
                .lookup("java:comp/env/wm/LMKGWM01");
```

What is the String argument passed in `lookup` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [post](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/asyncbns/concepts/casb_workmgr.html), it talks all about it.
The path is used for searching for the needed resource by JNDI (Java Naming and Directory Interface).

Comment: can u plz tell me Purpose of using this WorkManager in my application

Comment: Read  the post carefully from the beginning and you will understand where and why to use it.

Comment: Post doesn't exist anymore. Any alternative answer?

Comment: What about this one: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/commonj/work/WorkManager.html

Comment: But that doesn't mean you need to downvote it, no? At least that's my opinion.